# Save data in a local file with HTML, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, offline

I'd like to develop a simple offline html page to track my working hours. I'd need an offline file where I can put all my information and then retrieve them through Javascript. What do you suggest me? XML, Json, a DB? I need a "physical" local file because I would like to take my folder with all my html, css, and js files, put it in a pen drive and then open it in another computer. So something portable.

Comment: Use an external db like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com)

Comment: This might be a good use case for a small Electron app https://electronjs.org/ You have access to the filesystem and Node so you could write your DB locally, use SQLite, or whatever you want.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that offline; HTML/JavaScript doesn't have the ability to write to the filesystem. You can create cookies or use `.localStorage` in JavaScript, but that would only be local to your browser and won't be visible on another computer.

The closest thing you could possibly get is to write a page that stores data in `localStorage` and then run it from a portable version of your favorite browser that you also keep on your portable drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not set on only using HTML, you might look into doing a C# windows form application.

You can find more on how to leverage that StreamWriter Class here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

However as for file type, a local JSON or .csv file should do the trick.